# Flagging already closed question as duplicate

Tags: bug, questions, flags

I noticed that an already closed question was a duplicate (both questions were asked by the same user).  I flagged the new newest question of the two, clicked "Other" and typed this:

```
Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/<questionID>/<myUserID>
```

After I submitted the flag, I got the following message:

```
When flagging a duplicate, please specify the duplicate question (id or link).
```

Why did I get that error?  I included a link to the question right there in the message.

When I changed the message to:

```
This question is exactly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/<questionID>/<myUserID>
```

I was able to submit the flag just fine.

Comment: Was the question closed as "exact duplicate" or something else?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: It was closed as "not a real question".

Comment: It looks like the system isn't recognizing share URLs as duplicate question links. How very odd.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I think I had something similar, I wanted to flag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178668/ as duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/205759/ but I got the same message.

Comment: @Neil: That question was migrated to a different site, so I'm guessing the system is failing to recognize it as such and thinks you didn't specify the duplicate question link at all.